# Django - Get Foreign key value directly with custom db_column

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, model

I'm trying to do what's described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly

I have a model like this:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, default=None)
    baker = models.OneToOneField(User, to_field='username', parent_link=True, null=True,
                                       db_column="django_username", default=None, db_constraint=False)
```

I have a pizza instance, I want the actual username stored in the Pizza table without hitting the user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access the actual value of a `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField` column by appending "_id" to the field name

```
pizza.baker_id
```

Comment: A custom column name does not change this behavior. What do you get when you use baker_id?

Comment: Thanks.  It's funny, I assumed since I was using a custom column name that wouldn't work.  But I just tried it and it works.  Lesson learned.